# how to configure git to identify changes made by another developer as a conflict

Tags: git, version-control, repository, git-merge, git-rebase

I am trying to figure out if we can set up git to flag any file that has been changed by two or more developers as conflicted - regardless of whether or not the same lines inside that file were modified.  Here is an example:

Two developers start by cloning a remote repo on their local machines.  Developer 1 makes a change to file A.  Since he is the first developer to change the file, there are no conflicts and he then commits the changes to his local repo followed by pushing the change to the remote repo.  While developer 1 was working, developer 2 was also working on that same file, but in a completely different area so that there are no overlapping lines of code.  Developer 2 then commits his changes to his local repo and then does a pull.  At this point, git seems to do automatic merging of the lines.

This is ok sometimes.  But, there are other times when this is definitely not ok and that file needs to be reviewed and updated before it is pushed to the remote repo.  This is important enough and happens often enough that we really want to apply this to all files before pushing them to the repository.  So, the question is - can git merge be configured to identify a file as conflicted when it has been altered by another developer since the last pull?  I have looked at the git merge command [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html).  Even though it offers merge strategies, I did not see anything that would provide this capability.  It should not be hard to implement this capability either.  All that would need to be done is to determine if a developer's local repo version (from the last pull) for File A matches the current version for file A in the remote repo.  If not, then flag it as conflicted.  Any way this can be done, or any other ideas that we could use to identify files that have been altered and need to be reviewed before pushing to the repo?

Comment: So far I only read the title but sounds bad... The idea of conflict is well defined within Git. Are you trying to make Git identify conflicts where there aren't any?

Comment: @MarcellFülöp I want to be able to detect when another developer has updated the remote repo since it was pulled down by another developer so that developer can decide if his changes will need to be updated before checking in.  If git can not do it, then perhaps there is a gui tool out there that can?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say: don't try to do this inside `git merge`.  Instead, do it with an external script.  (You may have some problems getting developers to use the script of course :-) )

You can then make that script work just the way you suggested: compare "files in repo as of base, vs files in repo as of just-before-(merge/rebase)":

```
# if on branch foo that maps to origin/foo
git tag compare-foo <commit-id>
git fetch origin
git diff <optional-args> compare-foo origin/foo
# or use git diff-tree and do your own post-processing
# add more stuff to compare the merge-base to the
# developer's version of branch foo to identify files
# that were modified by "both"
# when all satisified: git tag -d compare-foo
```

To pick the commit ID, you might use `git merge-base`, e.g.:

```
cid=$(git merge-base foo origin/foo)
```

or you must just assume that `origin/foo` is the correct point, i.e., that developers run this process instead of updating `origin/foo` by doing a straight `git fetch`.  (Or, see fancy-up below.)

You will probably want to fancy up the process by requiring that developers "sign off" some sort of "I did the comparison and it's all OK" claim.  The details will be up to you and the developers, and that will drive the mechanism (e.g., you might want to create refs outside of the `refs/tags` name space and/or use `git notes` with a different name space than the usual notes).  Once signed-off, this can serve as a starting point for a subsequent comparison, should some other developer "beat them to it" in terms of successfully pushing commits.

Note: This is not a substitute for actual testing (but then, testing is not a substitute for eyeballing one's changes vs someone else's, either).

Comment: Is there a git gui tool like GitExtensions that can be used to enter the script and then have the difference program called in sequence for each file that is different?

Comment: I mostly avoid most of the GUIs.  I sometimes use gitk to visualize branches and that's about it.  So, I have no idea how you'd drive this from or with a GUI.